# When can preposition "by" be omitted?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I came across theses sentences:

> He made a fortune selling property in Spain.
>
> He paid for dinner using his credit card.

I want to know when it's okay to omit "by".

Please give answers based in grammar and not personal feelings.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a verb, you don't necessarily need a preposition. In both your examples, you can use one *or* the other:

> - He made a fortune **selling** (verb) property in Spain.
> - He made a fortune **from** (preposition) property in Spain.

Also:

> - He paid for dinner **using** (verb) his credit card.
> - He paid for dinner **by** (preposition) credit card.

In both these examples, the *meaning* is unaltered by using one or the other.

When you use a verb *and* a preposition together, it is called a *prepositional verb*. You only need to use these when it *alters the meaning*.

For example:

> - I believe John
> - I believe *in* John

These mean very different things - the first means you accept that John speaks truthfully; the second means that you have faith or confidence in John.

Also:

> - I knocked the door
> - I knocked *at* the door

The first means you accidentally damaged the door by colliding with it; the second idiomatically means that you struck against the door to attract attention.

So, simply put - you make a choice based on the meaning. In your examples, using a prepositional verb adds nothing to the sentences. If you need to know how to use a particular verb, look it up in a good dictionary and you will see examples of usage.

Comment: It was really helpful