# What is the difference in meaning between "I eat twice a day" and "I eat twice in a day"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Tell me please the difference in meaning between the following sentenced?

> I eat twice **a day**.
>
> I eat twice **in a day**.

I am sure that *in a day* is a valid phrase, but I cannot figure out the difference between it and *a day* as in my sentences.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* a valid phrase, but they mean different things.

- "Twice a day" means *every* day.
- "Twice *in* a day" would normally mean *a specific day*.

For example:

> I once ate six times in a day.

This refers to one specific occasion on which you ate 6 times in one day. It would **not** make sense to say "I once ate six times a day".

For some additional information on when to use a preposition with a verb, take a look at the answer to [this recent question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/237396/when-can-preposition-by-be-omitted/237405#237405).

Comment: You answer is getting it clearer, but let's say I ate six meals on one specific day, say, February 10, do I say "in the day" or "on the day". For example, "February 10 saw a lot of eating. I ate 6 meals in the day/on the day."

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope That's a completely different question - when to use the indefinite article "a" or the definite article "the". Look that up, you'll find it has already been answered.

Comment: Well, no. It is a very similar question. It is not about articles. It is about the preposition "in" and "on". Could you please read my question a little bit more carefully?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I've answered your question about "on", or "in" **a** day. You've now just asked a supplementary question which inserts "the" into the middle of it. That is a different question. I'll say this though - that as a native English speaker, my answer is the idiomatic way of saying it. If I thought it needed a different article, I would have changed it. But if you want to understand why, then you'll find it has been well answered on this site already.